# Cntrl + click not working in Android studio

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, cordova

I am new to Android Studio.I like the IDE very much,it has got some nice set of features and has a rich look and feel, however I have some issues with the IDE.  I recently created a Cordova application in android studio.I created an HTML file called index.html under assests/www folder.I included my jquery-1.11.3.min.js inside index.html file.I have the habit of checking whether the file ***jquery-1.11.3.min.js*** has been correctly included inside HTML file.In eclipse I use cntrl +click to check whether the js file path given is right.But when I use the same thing in Android studio,even if the path is right,it is showing like 'Cannot find declaration to go to'.The screenshot for the same is given below.

[image]

Can anyone suggest a solution for this situation.

Comment: May be the answer lies in the bug list. Did you tried to find that?

Comment: This isn't related a scripting in any way.

Comment: @Jai Where can I find the bug list

Comment: @ebiliga Sorry I don't get it.Do you mean Android studio can only be used to built native Android applications.